# slide.bs.carousel и slid.bs.carousel fade effect bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, karma

Есть слайдер где хочу реализовать fade effect между картинками. Хочу это сделать через Jquery.

Html:

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slider carousel-fade">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="..."/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>123</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="..."/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>123</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="..."/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>123</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
        </a>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
interval: 4000}).on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
$('.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active').fadeToggle(600);}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
$('.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active').fadeIn(600);});
```

Получается так, что иногда код отрабатывает, а иногда нет;

А если быстро переключаться между слайдами, бывает не упивается зафейдится картинка и в слайдере их становится две (пока не наступит фейд);

Как обойти и реализовать фейд эффект (только js/jquery)?

Comment: Виноват fadeOut(600) а не fadeToggle(600)
*опечатался

Comment: по идее fade это просто opacity который применяется в keyframes и всё

Comment: @keyframes это ж работа с css, а я хочу реализовать через jquery

Comment: ну так jquery на прямую сотрудничает с css , сначала любой слайдер пишут на css а потом уже вешают обработчики + keyframes

Comment: так мы можем добиться любого результата